# Comma separated string of selected values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation

I want to convert selected values into a comma separated string in MySQL.

My initial code is as follows:

```
SELECT id
FROM table_level
WHERE parent_id = 4;
```

Which produces:

```
'5'
'6'
'9'
'10'
'12'
'14'
'15'
'17'
'18'
'779'
```

My desired output would look like this:

```
"5,6,9,10,12,14,15,17,18,779"
```

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Check this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM table_level
WHERE parent_id = 4
GROUP BY parent_id;
```

Answer (score 13):

If you have multiple rows for parent_id.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM table_level where parent_id=4 GROUP BY parent_id;
```

If you want to replace space with comma.

```
SELECT REPLACE(id,' ',',') FROM table_level where parent_id=4;
```

Comment: Go for GROUP_CONCAT :)

Answer (score 9):

Use [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function of mysql.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM table_level where parent_id=4 GROUP BY parent_id;
```

It'll give you concatenated string like :

```
5,6,9,10,12,14,15,17,18,779
```

Answer (score 9):

First to `set group_concat_max_len`, otherwise it will not give you all the result:

```
SET GLOBAL  group_concat_max_len = 999999;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id)  FROM table_level where parent_id=4 group by parent_id;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT('"',GROUP_CONCAT(id),'"') FROM table_level 
where parent_id=4 group by parent_id;
```

Result will be

```
 "5,6,9,10,12,14,15,17,18,779"
```

Answer (score 6):

The default separator between values in a group is comma(,). To specify any other separator, use `SEPARATOR` as shown below.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR '|')
FROM `table_level`
WHERE `parent_id`=4
GROUP BY `parent_id`;
```

> 5|6|9|10|12|14|15|17|18|779

To eliminate the separator, then use `SEPARATOR ''`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR '')
FROM `table_level`
WHERE `parent_id`=4
GROUP BY `parent_id`;
```

Refer for more info [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: nice answers. on this example one space is possible after comma separated with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) method in mysql

Comment: does it returns string??

Comment: @Karunakar, I'm getting `blob` here.

Answer (score 1):

Just so for people doing it in SQL server: use `STRING_AGG` to get similar results.

Answer (score 1):

Using the GROUP_CONCAT, here is another way to make it flexible :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('"',id,'"') FROM table_level where parent_id=4 GROUP BY parent_id;
```

This will return the values as :

```
"181","187","193","199","205","211","217","223","229","235","239","243","247","251"
```

You can concat using any other separator. This will help in case you want to use the return value directly somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you do not have field, which can be used for "GROUP BY" part. You may create "fake field" for it. Sample query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), "fake" as fakeField FROM table WHERE .... GROUP BY fakeField
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids FROM table_level where parent_id=4 group by parent_id;
```