# sql query to get multiple row value and echo in single row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**data in tables  like below..**

```
col1    col2   col3

100      700     500

100      700     501

100      700     502

101      701     503

101      701     504

101      701     505
```

Suppose user enter col1 = 100 and click search then it display like below in single row...

```
col1       col2          col3

100        700           500,501,502
```

**I need sql query which select all col3 value and display in single Row.**

plz help me to get this....

Comment: just use a while loop in php

Comment: possible duplicate of [comma separated string of selected values in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558443/comma-separated-string-of-selected-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  GROUP_CONCAT(col3) as col3
FROM
  table1
WHERE 
  col1=100
GROUP BY col1,col2
```