# How to get comma separated values from a table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

This is my **Categories Table**:

```
id  | name
 1    a
 2    b
 3    c
 4    d
```

In which I need to get the values of **1** and **2** in comma separated manner, i.e. **a,b**.

I tried something like this:

```
$ids = array('0'=>1,'1'=>2);
\DB::select('SELECT group_concat(name) as name from category where id = ?', ($ids));
```

But it always returns the first value (i.e., **a**)

I need the resultant values to be like this: **a,b**.

How could I do this either using normal query or by Laravel?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558443/comma-separated-string-of-selected-values-in-mysql

Comment: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name)  FROM category where id IN(1,2)`

Comment: Thank you so much It worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a kind of concatenation that can be achieved by using `GROUP_CONCAT` like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM category where id IN(1,2)
```

[Reference](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

**Explanation:** here `GROUP_CONCAT(name)` concat name as name1, name2 ... for the `WHERE` condition matched

Answer (score 1):

Try this using simple concat. You can concat as much as columns separated by commas.

Query - `select concat(id,",",name) as name from category where id = ?`

Answer (score 1):

### Try this

```
$data = \DB::table("articles")
   ->select("title")
   ->whereRaw("find_in_set('find value',colum_name)")
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Elequent ORM

```
Category::pluck('id')->join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

POST or GET data field `user_id = 1,2,3;`

```
$user_array = explode(',',Input::get('user_id')); OR $user_array = explode(',',Input::POST('user_id'));
$all_user =   User::WhereIn('user_id',$user_array)->get();
```

Get all user which have User ID 1,2 and 3.