# Mysql Get one column from one table and matched multiple records in the 2nd table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

- `Classrooms`
- `Courses`
- `Members`

[Screenshot of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BrAd.png)

This is the `members` table

```
-----------------------------------------
|  Member Name  |     Preferences       |
-----------------------------------------  
|    Jhon Doe   |    CS201,CS304,CS604  |
|    Neo        |    CS201,CS504,CS302  |
|    Jhon       |    CS201,CS701,CS704  |
-----------------------------------------
```

Rules for preferences :

- If there are more than one faculty member willing to take a course then preferred faculty member for that courses will be the one with higher designation (e.g. CS201 and CS304 in the above ‘Preference List’ table).

My question :

How can I get the preferences of the members from the given members who are willing to take the one course among their`s preferences courses

```
------------------------------------------------------
|  Course-Code  |     Willing Members   |  Preferred |
------------------------------------------------------  
|    CS201      |     Jhon Doe,Neo,Jhon |       Neo  |
|    CS304      |     Jhon Doe,Neo,Jhon |       Jhon |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: For the Willing Members column, you can use GROUP_CONCAT. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558443/comma-separated-string-of-selected-values-in-mysql

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @jelliaes it doesn`t  work for me i did but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a [join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) between the `courses` and the `members` table on the common attribute; `course_id`. The result is to be [grouped](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) on the course_id and prefer fields so as to obtain the willing members using [group_concat function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/). Here is the query:

```
SELECT A.course_id `Course-Code`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.name ORDER BY B.name SEPARATOR ',') 
`Willing Members`, B.prefer `Preferred` FROM courses A
LEFT JOIN members B ON A.course_id=B.course_id
GROUP BY A.course_id, B.prefer;
```

Comment: i Group_CONCAT that worked ,but how can i get the prefer member among the willing members on the basis of above preferences  rule ?